# Making spaces "verbatim" characters in fixed-width font

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

Is there any way to make spaces in fixed-width fonts behave like a space character with the same extent as non-space characters?

I can do it manually with `\phantom` but it's tedious; row 2 below is what I want. (and why the extra space after the colon in row 1?)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% phantom space
\def\psp{\phantom{0}} 

\node[anchor=west] at (0,0) {\tt 1: A B  C 0 F};
\node[anchor=west] at (0,-0.5cm) {\tt 2:\psp A\psp B\psp\psp C\psp 0\psp F};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: note `\tt` is not defined by default in latex.  `\obeyspaces` is probably what you are looking for (the space is set to be monospaced, but by default multiple spaces count as one)

Comment: hmm `\obeyspaces` seems to solve the multiple spaces not being coalesced... what about the space after a colon?

Comment: `\frenchspacing`

Comment: huh it looks like the `text width` is the culprit causing differences between 3 and 4

Comment: 3 and 4 ? not sure what you refer to here?

Comment: see edits -- inter-word spacing seems to be modified

Comment: never mind, I'll open a different question for that

Comment: relocated to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530004/why-does-text-width-affect-space-widths-and-how-can-i-stop-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `\obeyspaces` so that multiple spaces are not compressed to a single space token.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% phantom space
\def\psp{\phantom{\ttfamily 0}} 

\node[anchor=west] at (0,0) {\obeyspaces\frenchspacing\ttfamily{}1: A B  C 0 F};
\node[anchor=west] at (0,-0.5cm) {\ttfamily 2:\psp A\psp B\psp\psp C\psp 0\psp F};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]