# Why does text width affect space widths and how can I stop it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

What's making row 1 below different from the others? Space width is reduced. (This seems to be enabled by the `text width=something` style; if I remove it, the compression isn't there, but then I get centered text.) And is there any way to fix it but force the node width? (e.g. for drawing the node border)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
bytesbox/.style={minimum width = 10cm, text width=10cm, align=left},
}

\node[bytesbox, anchor=west] at (0,1cm) {\tt 1 AB CD EF GH IJ KL};
\node[bytesbox, anchor=west] at (0,0.5cm) {\tt 2.AB.CD.EF.GH.IJ.KL};
\node[anchor=west] at (0,0) {\tt 3 AB CD EF GH IJ KL};
\node[anchor=west] at (0,-0.5) {\tt 4 AB.CD.EF.GH.IJ.KL};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `node font=\ttfamily` (or `font=\ttfamily`), `\tt` or wrapping the text of the nodes in `\texttt` are (AFAIK) wrong. The pgfmanual v3.1.5b says on p. 233

[image]

And you need `align=flush left`. The pgfmanual v3.1.5b says on p. 236

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  bytesbox/.style={minimum width = 10cm, text width=10cm, align=flush left},
}

\node[bytesbox, anchor=west,node font=\ttfamily] at (0,1cm) {1 AB CD EF GH IJ KL};
\node[bytesbox, anchor=west,node font=\ttfamily] at (0,0.5cm) {2.AB.CD.EF.GH.IJ.KL};
\node[anchor=west,node font=\ttfamily] at (0,0) {3 AB CD EF GH IJ KL};
\node[anchor=west,node font=\ttfamily] at (0,-0.5) {4 AB.CD.EF.GH.IJ.KL};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can add the font information to the `bytesbox` style.

```
\tikzset{
  bytesbox/.style={minimum width = 10cm, text width=10cm, align=flush left,node font=\ttfamily},
}
```

Comment: Well, `flush left` essentially does `text badly ragged`. The `font=` option can be useful, but it's not necessary as we're not interested in the `em` value that TikZ uses to set `\spaceskip`, as we *don't want* it to.

Comment: what's the difference between `flush left` and `text badly ragged` ? I see your excerpt from pgfmanual on flush left... from a typesetting standpoint I know what flush left means, I can see what `\raggedright` is I guess... `text badly ragged` is badly named though.

Comment: @egreg Well, more than 80% of the questions of the type "why is the spacing of my node off" can be answered by "because you did not use `node font` (or `font`)", so there is really no reason to propagate unfortunate practice further. Of course, you can always get the result in other ways as suggested by the manual, but if you follow the manual you are fine.

Comment: @JasonS It may just be me but I fail to see `text badly ragged` in the manual, so I cannot comment on that one. All I can say is that, according to what I find, if one follows the manual, there is no problem. (There are other cases in which the manual is not quite correct, but here it seems to be great.)

Answer (score 4):

It's Ti*k*Z that tampers with `\spaceskip` in text boxes.

You can solve this with `text badly ragged`. Please, avoid `\tt` that has been deprecated for 25 years.

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  bytesbox/.style={minimum width = 10cm, text width=10cm, align=left,text badly ragged},
}

\node[bytesbox, anchor=west] at (0,1cm) {\texttt{1 AB CD EF GH IJ KL}};
\node[bytesbox, anchor=west] at (0,0.5cm) {\texttt{2.AB.CD.EF.GH.IJ.KL}};
\node[anchor=west] at (0,0) {\texttt{3 AB CD EF GH IJ KL}};
\node[anchor=west] at (0,-0.5) {\texttt{4 AB.CD.EF.GH.IJ.KL}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: " Please, avoid \tt that has been deprecated for 25 years." -- how are we supposed to learn about these things?!

Comment: and what does `text badly ragged` actually do? just not touch the `\spaceskip`?

Comment: @JasonS It does `\raggedright`, which is good for you.

Comment: @JasonS I did comment on your previous question that `\tt` was not defined by default:-)

Answer (score 2):

`\spaceskip=0.5em` seems to allow me to fix it. (not sure why it's `0.5em` rather than `1em`)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
bytesbox/.style={minimum width = 10cm, text width=10cm, align=left},
bytesbox2/.style={minimum width = 10cm, text width=10cm, font={\ttfamily}, align=left, execute at begin node={\spaceskip 0.5em}},
}
% phantom space
\def\psp{\phantom{0}} 

\node[bytesbox, anchor=west] at (0,1cm) {\tt\spaceskip=0.5em 1 AB CD EF GH IJ KL};
\node[bytesbox, anchor=west] at (0,0.5cm) {\tt 2.AB.CD.EF.GH.IJ.KL};
\node[anchor=west] at (0,0) {\tt 3 AB CD EF GH IJ KL};
\node[anchor=west] at (0,-0.5) {\tt 4 AB.CD.EF.GH.IJ.KL};
\node[bytesbox2, anchor=west] at (0,-1cm) {5 AB CD EF GH IJ KL};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The default monospace font has the same character width as a digit, which is half the width of the Computer Modern em-width.  (In other words, that's a design decision.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton which is true but it means that the width of an M is half an em, which is ... unusual.

Comment: ... Half the width of a Computer Modern Roman em-width.  There's probably a comment in the Metafont recipe in Volume E.

Comment: @barbarabeeton not just cm roman though, em is font-specific so a cmtt M is half a cmtt em wide.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- What I'm trying to say, though obviously not very well, is that the `cmtt` em width is the same as that of the `cmr` em.  A design decision.  (I haven't explored, but it would be interesting to learn what the em width is for some non-cm monowidth fonts, say Courier or the Lucida mono.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton but it the same em!  cmr 1em is 10.00002pt  cmtt 1em is 10.4999pt width of tt M is 5.24995pt

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- I stand corrected.